# Is it possible to the change filenames of feature.xml and elements.xml on a sharepoint server?

Tags: feature

Is it possible to the change filenames of feature.xml and elements.xml on a sharepoint server if so how?

Comment: Why would you want/need to?

Comment: myself i have doubt

Answer (score 2):

**Feature.xml**
Regarding Feature.xml the "can I" answer depends on the version of SharePoint:

> **SharePoint 2007**: Yes, you can. To install it you must use `stsadm -o installfeature -filename myfeaturedir\myfeature.xml` and the feature wont be installed as part of deploying a solution
>
> **SharePoint 2010**: No, you can't both STSADM and Install-SPFeature requires the filename to be feature.xml

The "should I" answer is always NO.

**Elements.xml**
The Elements.xml name isn't special. It's an attribute of your `<ElementManifest>` entries in Feature.xml. When you're having multiple different SharePoint artifacts in you Feature it's very common to name the ElementManist files depending on what they contain.
If your feature only contain a single SharePoint artifact (which I'll recommend) then it's common the just name it Elements.xml as the Feature hopefully describes what's in it.

**Clarification**
You mention change it on the server, but hopefully you mean in Visual Studio when developing your WSP solution package. You should **NEVER** add/change any feature on the server except by adding/upgrading/removing WSP packages

Comment: `You mention change it on the server, but hopefully you mean in Visual Studio when developing your WSP solution package. You should NEVER add/change any feature on the server except by adding/upgrading/removing WSP packages` Quoted @Per because that, is worth repeating.